# Images not showing and plugins not installing on wordpress server move

Tags: plugins, images, ftp

I have recently moved my wordpress site from localhost to an apache server with plesk. Upon doing this my images are not appearing on the website despite still being in the media folder (however I cannot see them in uploads despite that being their url path). Also when I try and install plugins wordpress asks for ftp login details and even when they are correct, the install fails. I have seen a number of potential solutions online, none of which seem to be working for me! Does anyone know if this may just be a case of the hosting company changing permissions? I did change them all temporarily to 777 in ftp but that still didnt solve the issue. My woocommerce importer won't even allow me to import csvs at the moment!

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated as there seems to be one thing after another on this server move:)

Matt

Comment: Please, add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your Question ([edit]). Also, check this [troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) guide.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do:

In your wp-config.php file, hardcode your new site URL by entering

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.example.com');
```

After that, have a look at the source code of your pages including images, and verify how the URLs of the the images look like. If they are wrong (relative to localhost?), you may have to run a little search/replace on your database.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Since posting that however I have set permissions to 777 on some other folders and it has worked. I don't want to leave them as 777 though so would you or anyone know if there is a way around this?

Comment: In the mean time the Standard permissions for WordPress installations is:
755 for directories and 644 for files.